# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError: Method

Tags: android, java-native-interface

filemane: bmp-parsing.cpp

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_happy_MainActivity_bmpParsing( JNIEnv* env,
    jintArray bmapColorArray)
{
    return 0;
}
```

package com.example.happy;

```
public native int bmpParsing(int[] Array);
static {
    System.loadLibrary("bmp-parsing");
}

int[] Array = new int[bmapColorArraySize];
Log.d("JNI Test", "Return: " + bmpParsing(Array));
```

when I call the native function, it says "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: bmpParsing".
Please help.

Comment: what is your activity name in which `bmpParsing(int[] Array)` method resides ?

Answer (score 2):

Add jobject to your JNI method and then try  it will work fine

```
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_happy_MainActivity_bmpParsing( JNIEnv* env ,jobject obj,
    jintArray bmapColorArray)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made up that 'C' function signature. Use the one that is generated for you by javah. That's what it's for.